# Gmail not recognizing JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org, google-schemas, json-ld

I am attempting to test Gmail's capabilities to process embedded JSON-LD in an HTML message in order to show the relevant action in the Inbox view, the introduction of which is described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/getting-started).  I have sent myself a message (using the Python API), for which I expect Gmail to render my View Action, an example of which is shown [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#view_action).  However, nothing is happening.  I am expecting to see a link for "View File", similar to one that would be displayed for flight reservations, etc.

I'm trying to understand if there is a problem with my particular JSON-LD content, or if I'm trying to do something that isn't supported.  The relevant JSON-LD segment, as embedded in the `<body>`, is this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "CreativeWork",
  "@id": "http://my-site.com/file/1",
  "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Computer_file",
  "name": "My File",
  "description": "View this file",
  "url": "http://my-site.com/file/1",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "url": "http://my-site.com/file/1",
    "name": "View File"
  }
}
</script>
```

In case there is some issue with the way the email is encoded, here it is in raw format (personal info redacted)

```
Received: from 874510238733-ktbae5ftk223du75th86q0uua7i7rp5v.apps.googleusercontent.com
    named unknown
    by gmailapi.google.com
    with HTTPREST;
    Fri, 6 Mar 2015 14:54:52 -0800
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="===============5111695568485418487=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
to: ****@gmail.com
subject: A file has been shared to your email
Date: Fri, 6 Mar 2015 14:54:52 -0800
Message-Id: <CADTCK+Vyd-bKWBJXMcs8eS1zQ-b34BanFzNKOBMVf_2dBiPB3A@mail.gmail.com>
From: ****@gmail.com

--===============5111695568485418487==
Content-Type: text/text; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


A new file is available.  View this file <http://my-site.com/file/1>

--===============5111695568485418487==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<body>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "CreativeWork",
  "@id": "http://my-site.com/file/1",
  "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/id/Computer_file",
  "name": "My File",
  "description": "View this file",
  "url": "http://my-site.com/file/1",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "url": "http://my-site.com/file/1",
    "name": "View File"
  }
}
</script>

<div>A new file is available.  <a href="http://my-site.com/file/1" target="_blank">View this file</a></div>

</body>
</html>

--===============5111695568485418487==--
```

Comment: I discovered a few things through testing with the Google Apps Script.  It seems Gmail *only* allows http://schema.org/EmailMessage as the type, even though that doesn't appear to be documented anywhere.  Also, it requires the `@context` to be just http://schema.org string.  No external contexts, no abbreviations, or the entire document is not recognized.  Would be great if I could locate all these rules documented somewhere instead of having to discover them by trial and error.

Comment: Regarding "Would be great if I could locate all these rules documented somewhere instead of having to discover them by trial and error", there is a markup tester so you can verify your markup: https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/